# Adobe Air - Choose webcam manually

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

How to choose the webcam/camera manually in Adobe Air? In Flash it's working through this:

```
Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.CAMERA);
```

Is there something like that in Adobe Air?
Thank

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Do you really need that typical dialog?
You can set a camera manually first by showing a list by:

```
var cameraNames:Array = Camera.names;
```

And then.....

```
var cameraInstance:Camera = Camera.getCamera('selectedCameraName');
```

Answer (score 5):

In the Adobe Air Player (up to 3.4) there is no equivalent of the Flash Player security panel that can be triggered with `Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.CAMERA);`

If you want to let the user pick a camera, you will have to create some sort of menu by using the info from the `Camera.names` array. Then, you can assign the user's choice via code by using something like :

```
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera('1');
```

Important: contrary to what was said above you CANNOT specify the camera by name. The `getCamera()` function expects a string representation of the camera's index number as a parameter. This is weird behaviour but it's how it works. So if you want to retrieve the second camera, you will have to pass the string `'1'` to the `getCamera()` function.

If you try to set the camera by specifying it's name, the function will return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any feature that you can use to select camera in AIR.

Instead you have to do it by coding.

get list of cameras using Camera.names property and then get selected camera instance using Camera.getCamera("name of camera");

I think this is best way to Do it.